# Compile C# DLL with dependencies (including .NET framework)

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Is it possible to compile all the C# project to one DLL with .NET dependencies to run it on Windows computers without .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get Spoon

http://spoon.net/studio

it will do what you are asking

Comment: It requires `Spoon` environment only to build a package or on recipient machine too?

Answer (score 0):

No but there are other solutions to running it on computers without the .NET framework such as using a virtual machine, Remote Thin Clients, Web Based Clients etc etc.

What computer is there that can't run .NET anyway? With mono you can pretty much run it everywhere.

Comment: I want to create stand-alone DLL to run it with legacy Delphi applications on Windows machines without .NET

Comment: well it really depends on what sort of application you are planning on making then. I don't know a great deal about delphi, does it support remoting into windows?

would a web service do the job?

Comment: Out company uses Delphi 6 for legacy applications, and we cannot get WCF-service working with Delphi 6

Comment: have you tried running the WCF service on another system and then connecting to it from the Delphi System using HTTP?

Comment: What do you mean? Surely Delphi has support for HTTP

Comment: @skayred: AFAIR, D6 has SOAP support and, at least, pure HTTP support with Indy. What settings does your WCF service use?

Comment: I don't know, but it works fine with C#. I've tryed Delphi with `wsdlimp` but got `Access violation` when calling service method